# do nothing if require parameter is empty (react js)

Tags: json, reactjs

I have the following codeline:

```
var json = require('path/to/jsonFile.json);
```

within a Component. Is it possible to check if this File is empty before this error is thrown?

```
Syntax error: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: What's your actual json file look like? It looks to me like the json is jsonFile.json isn't structured properly

Comment: maybe wrap the require inside a try catch ?

Comment: @JoshSiegl this file will be generated during runtime so it could be possible that something fails and I end up with an empty file. In this case nothing should be shown.

Comment: FYI on your deleted question from today  `var newArr = arr.map(function(elem) {
  return {
    name: elem.name,
    age: elem.age
  };
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top on your component, you can write

```
try{
    var json = require('path/to/json')
}
catch(error) {
    var json = undefined;
}
```

now, there is no error throws at run time and you can check if json is undefined to do your stuff on the json file

Comment: pleased to have helped